# " sudo: source: command not found"

Tags: shell, sudo

```
$ source /etc/environment 

$ sudo source /etc/environment 
[sudo] password for t: 
sudo: source: command not found
```

It seems that a different shell than `bash` is run to execute `source /etc/environment` and that shell doesn't have `source` as builtin.

But my and the root's default shells are both `bash`.

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

If `sudo` indeeds uses a different shell, why is it? I saw [slm's reply](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/143860/674), but don't understand in my case.

Comment: `source` is a shell builtin..you can not use `sudo` to run a shell builtin like an external command..

Comment: Is the issue that you cannot read the file, or that you want the environment defined in the file to apply to subsequent sudo commands?

Comment: @Random832:  want the environment defined in the file to apply to subsequent sudo commands

Answer (score 34, accepted):

`source` is a shell builtin, so it cannot be executed without the shell. However, by default, `sudo` do not run shell. From [`sudo`](http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo)

> **Process model**
>
> When sudo runs a command, it calls fork(2), sets up the execution environment as described above, and calls the execve system call in the child process

If you want to explicitly execute shell, use `-s` option:

```
# sudo -s source /etc/environment
```

Which is still useless because after shell is exited, environment changes are lost.

Comment: This worked for me. I just ran into an error though which I thought I might share it and its workaround as it might happen to you too. `/root: Is a directory`. I think it is a common problem when inserting your environment variables using `vi` or `vim`. I turned out that the `.sh` file which I tried to `source` has a tilde character  ("  `  ") at the end of it. By removing it from the file, `sudo -s source /etc/environment` worked without no error.

Answer (score 12):

In the realm of [solving the problem rather than answering the question](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130620-00/?p=4033), here's the most obvious (to me) way to source a file which only root can read:

```
source <(sudo cat /etc/environment)
```

This uses [process substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_substitution).  It takes the output of the `cat` command and turns it into a pseudo-file, which you can pass to `source`.  source then runs the commands in the current shell.

Note that on most systems, `/etc/environment` is world-readable, so you *ought* to be able to just run this:

```
source /etc/environment
```

Comment: this works, the accepted one doesn't

Answer (score 2):

`sudo` expects a command but you are giving a shell builtin so it cannot find the command. If you write `type source`, you can see the output: `source is a shell builtin` and the output of `which source` is empty.

For example `sudo strace` will work and `which strace` will give output because strace is a command.

Edit: Also, you can see `sudo su;sudo source /etc/environment` works nicely so  different shell is not used.