# Why print command can not be called with sudo?

Tags: zsh, sudo, shell-builtin

```
% print ok
ok
% sudo print ok
sudo: print: command not found
```

It seems the `print` are not properly loaded. So what happened and how can I fix it?

Comment: Related: [“ sudo: source: command not found”](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/202332/315749)

Answer (score -1):

I found the reason should be that `sudo` command invokes the `sh` as a default shell to root user, and there is no command called 'print' in `sh`.

Comment: No, `sudo` doesn't invoke `sh`, it executes the command directly (unless you pass the `-s` option, in which case it invokes the shell specified in `$SHELL` after having attempts to quotes the arguments). `print` is a builtin command in ksh or zsh, some systems don't have a standalone `print` command, and on those that have one, it's generally got nothing to do with `zsh`'s `print` builtin.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas But if the shell didn't get changed, why the `print` can not be found in the same environment of the case without a `sudo`? The `sudo` command explicitly refuses to run it?

Comment: `zsh` executes the `sudo` command, and then `sudo` tries to execute the `print` command. There is no such command on your system, only a builtin command in the `zsh` shell. You'd need `sudo zsh -c 'print ok'` for `sudo` to execute a `zsh` command (which contrary to `print` does exist, probably in `/bin` or somewhere else, see the output of `type print zsh`), to interpret that `print ok` inline script. And that `zsh` would invoke its own `print` builtin command with `ok` as argument.