# source inside a shell script

Tags: shell, source

## config.sh

```
hi="/home/user"
date_sec=`date '+%s'`
```

this is my file1.

## main.sh

```
source config.sh
cd $hi
echo "$date_sec"
```

The source is not working in main.sh

Comment: What language are you using? Is it `sh` or `bash` or something else?

Comment: ... and what is the error message?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [sudo source: command not found](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/143858/sudo-source-command-not-found)

Comment: Welcome to Unix & Linux! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Some shells requires the file that you `source` to be available in your `$PATH` unless you give a path to the script:

```
$ ksh93 main.sh
main.sh[1]: .: config.sh: cannot open [No such file or directory]
```

Changing the command to

```
source ./config.sh
```

should fix this.

Also, `.` (dot) is more portable than `source` and works with e.g. `dash` and should also work with any other shell masquerading as `sh`:

```
. ./config.sh
```

Apart from that, [consider using `$( ... )` rather than backticks in new scripts](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated), and [remember to quote your variables](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells). I'd also suggest [using `printf` rather than `echo` for variable output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo).